# SVG Logo as image vs background vs inline

Tags: css, svg

I know this question may be considered as opinion based, but I havent found any answer on the net and would like to know the advantages and cons of every solution!
I want to display the logo in an svg format, but hesitating a lot between:

1- `<img src="logo.svg" ... />`: IE9+ which is fine for me

2- `<a href="#" id="logo">Company</a>` + its own css

3- `<svg ...><path ...>`: 1 HTTP request less :D

which one is the best and why?

Thanks a lot

Comment: #1 requires an `http` request.  #3 will bloat your document as it will not be cached. Use #2. Convert the SVG to base64 and set it as the background using CSS. This combines the benefits of caching and reduces your total http requests by 1.

Comment: @Ihazkode why wouldn't #3 use cache? .html should be cached too. b64 encoding -> size x 1.34. To OP: it will depend on each cases, but one more possibility for monochrome icons, if you've got a lot is to create a web-font.

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply and reactivity :) I also read about setting the image as background and convert it with base64, but this article made me a little sceptic: http://dev.mobify.com/blog/data-uris-are-slow-on-mobile/ :S

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the background as if you need something to poke then you will not need to use the developer or crawl into the code. It is best that the entire visual part of the site is set by styles

Comment: thank for your reply. and sorry, didn't really understand what you mean!

Comment: @Websphere I mean that all visible part of site must be written in css file (bg and other rules)

Comment: @Websphere use bg for logo image

Answer (score 0):

1 :

`<img src="logo.svg" alt="..." />`

This will load your `svg` file into `img` tag which will be +1 request into your total number of requests.

2 :

`<a href="#" id="logo">Company</a>`

If you want to give your own CSS then also your request be +1 with total number of requests.

3 :

`<svg ...><path .../></svg>`

You have to have .AI file to convert it into **svg code**.
This will be loaded along with your code.

It is good that you include your logo into your svg code if you are concerning about network request. If it doesn't matter then you can include it into CSS as other developers won't have to worry about svg code.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do have the logo in .ai format.

For solution 2: i think there will be a request even if it's loaded in my CSS file, no? I'm currently using a cdn that uses HTTP2, should I still care about http requests?

Comment: Oh.. yes.. that will be , too. well , it depends on you that you want to have +1 request or not. I would suggest that go with **svg code**. if it really matters.